# Don't expand `%` in external grep call

Tags: regular-expression, search, external-command, the-silver-searcher

I try to search for `{% amount` in all files under the current directory.

Using [ag](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher), this works fine:

```
ag -Q '{% amount'
```

(`-Q` specify to not use any regex, try to match text literally)

I have this in my `.vimrc`:

```
grepprg=ag --nogroup --nocolor --column
```

And when I use `:grep -Q '{% amount'` I get the following error:

> E499: Empty file name for '%' or '#', only works with ":p:h"

Which (in my understanding) mean that Vim try to expand `%` and fail (because I've not opened any file).

My question is: How to search for a litteral `%` when using external grep program?

---

**Note:** thanks to [statox](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/1841/statox) I know that the following works:

```
:vimgrep /%/ *
```

Comment: escape the '%' using '\', e.g. use '\%'

Comment: Thanks, cannot believe it this simple! If you want to make that an answer, I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Vim command line, the `%` is a special placeholder for the current buffer name. See `:help cmdline-special`. To avoid the expansion, just escape the character with a backslash: `:grep -Q '{\% amount'`